# formValidation with datetimepicker and format('LLLL')

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation-plugin

I am displaying the time in the datetimepicker in the format LLLL by using the following options

```
$('#meeting_datetime').datetimepicker({defaultDate: tomorrowsDate, stepping: 5, format: 'LLLL'});
```

all that works fine, but now I would like to validate that field and I thought it should just work as

```
$('#manage_jc_settings_form')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            excluded: ':disabled',
            ignore: [],
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                meeting_datetime: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'LLLL',
                            message: 'The date is not valid'
                        },
                        callback: {
                            message: "The next meeting can't be in the past",
                            callback: function (value, validator) {
                                var m = new moment(value, 'LLLL', true);
                                return (m > todaysDate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

but this way the datetime field does not validate. Does anybody know how to use the LLLL format in the validation? I am using the formValidation plugin http://formvalidation.io/
thanks
carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date validation type does not support that type of formatting.  You need to use the callback validation type with moment.  However, since you already have a callback type and need to return a different message, you need to use the Dynamic message.

http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/#dynamic-message-example

```
function(value, validator, $field) {
    // ... Do your logic checking
    if (...) {
        return {
            valid: true,    // or false
            message: 'The error message'
        }
    }

    return {
        valid: false,       // or true
        message: 'Other error message'
    }
}
```

Then do a check for the validity of the date and return one message for that.  And check the date is greater than the todaysDate and return a different message for that.

Answer (score 0):

If todaysDate is not a moment then create it:

```
todaysMomentDate = moment(todaysDate);
```

Then compare them:

```
var diffDuration = moment.duration(m.diff(todaysMomentDate);
return diffDuration.asMilliseconds() < 0;
```

Comment: hi... sorry I should have cut down the example further. It is not the callback function which does not validate... this function works fine. It is the date format validation which fails. Therefore I mentioned the LLLL format in the title

Comment: oh, I see.  I would include in your question what framework you are using to do the validation as there are many, and I can't find the one you are using.  Note that "LLLL" is not a standard javascript notation.  It is implemented by libraries like moment, but it may not be the same for whichever validation library you are using.

Comment: yes that is my suspicion as well, but from the docs I could not figure out how to validate this particular format... I am using formValidation http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: You can stuff both checks into the callback type.  I added another answer that explains that.  Cool library.